# Passing ID parameter to an aspx modal window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a repeater control that contains a hyperlink which the user will click to launch a custom aspx modal window. The hyperlink contains the "record id" value.

The user clicks the hyperlink, the code passes from code behind to javascript, which launches the custom aspx window.

How do I pass the record id parameter from javascript function so that the aspx modal window being launched can retreieve it, and run a sql query with that value.

I am open to creating a session value, a hidden html control (I tried the hidden control, but was not able to pass the value) or any other options.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You say the hyperlink contains the record ID and next you ask how to pass the record ID? I do not understand, since the first part seems to be the answer to the second part.

Comment: sorry... what I mean is that I can pass the parameter to the javascript function. How can I pass it from the javascript function to the aspx modal window?

Comment: Simply pass it to the `window.open` function call.

Comment: can't do that because the client has a specific function to call the modal window. However, your suggestion gave me an idea that I can pass the value as a querystring. Thanks Uwe !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you write, the most obvious solution would be to pass the ID as the part of the address. Like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <a href="javascript:ChildWindowUrl?ID=<'%# ((MyEntityType)Container.DataItem).ID %'> >child window</a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I already have that part working. I can pass the parameter to the javascript page. How do I pass from the javascript page to the aspx modal window?

Comment: for example... your code block that you wrote, I have something similar like.... <a href="javascript:ChildWindowUrl?ID=<'%....